# getting an error in false if statement

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript function with an if statement; the variables col and top are passed to the function as arguments:

```
 if (col == 'persact') {
     for (j = 1; j <= top; j++) {
         var coluid = "xx_" + j;
         var colu = document.getElementById(coluid).value;
         var colidj = "x_" + j;

         if (colu == "PersActNumOrd") {
             var numordid = colidj;
             var numord = document.getElementById(numordid).value;
         }
         if (colu == "PersActUnitChg") {
             var unitchgid = colidj;
             var unitchg = document.getElementById(unitchgid).value;
         }
         if (colu == "PersActExt") {
             var extid = colidj;
             var extold = document.getElementById(extid).value;
         }...similar stuff...
     } //j loop
 } //persact if
```

The function was correctly invoked for a case where col != 'persact'.  The function ran properly, but I got an error from firebug:

*TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

document.getElementById(extid).value = exten*

Well, of course it is null.  That's why it was in a conditional block.  Could someone explain why an error is being detected when the if condition was false and that block of code should not have run.  Is this just firebug being stupid, or is there a deeper explanation having to do with the way javascript operates?

Another mystery here is that the error was for "extid" but the previous two (and several following document.getElementById statements, which also should have been null did not produce an error.

Comment: Which one is giving the error?

Comment: Your question is not clear. How does `col == 'persact'` correlate with the `colidj` element existing in the document?

Comment: What is inside the else portion of the outer if-statement listed here (what is executed when `col!='persact'`)?

Comment: Did you missed the quotation mark intentionally - document.getElementById("numordid").value?

Comment: To answer all the comments: 1. It is extid which is giving the error. 2. The value "col" is passed as a parameter to the function. It indicates which is the underlying table, and there is only one table for which I want to run this if statement.  The values of that table are in the input statements which trigger the function and they have id's like x_1, x_2.  The purpose of the if statement is to pick up the ids of some of the columns I must manipulate later if col = persact.  (continued in next comment)

Comment: 3.  There is no "else" portion of this statement.  If col != 'persact' there is no action to be taken.  4.  numordid and all the others are set as Javascript variables immediately before being referenced in the getElementById method.  Since they are Javascript variables,and not literals, there should not be quotes around them.

Comment: For what it is worth, I found out what the problem is.  My closure on the  if (col == 'persact') statement was in the wrong place.  So extid was indeed showing up outside the if statement.  I must be more careful next time, but am relieved that Firebug was indeed telling me the truth.